# count variable grouped by two variables

Tags: r, data.table, plyr, reshape

We all know the function `table` in R. I'm searching for a function to get the same Output when using `table(x,y)` but not with counts for each combination of values of x and y but for another variable z. In data.table, this is possible by `dt[,sum(z),by=c("x","y")]`. But that doesn't give me an output equal to the table(x,y)- output. I tried dcast but also didn't get what I wanted

```
 dt <- data.table(y=rep(letters[1:2],each=3),x=rep(letters[1:2],length=6),z=rep(letters [7],length=6))  
   y x z
1: a a g
2: a b g
3: a a g
4: b b g
5: b a g
6: b b g
```

It should have this output, but with counts of g:

```
    y
 x   a b
   a 2 1
   b 1 2
```

I would like to have these results, but in the form of a table:

```
   x y V1
1: a a  2
2: b a  1
3: b b  2
4: a b  1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
DF <- data.frame(y=rep(letters[1:2],each=3),
                 x=rep(letters[1:2],length=6),
                 z=rep(letters [7],length=6)) 

tapply(X=DF$z, INDEX=list(DF$x, DF$y), FUN=length)
#  a b
#a 2 1
#b 1 2
```

Comment: Thanks, this is funny, I totally forgot tapply while working with data.table!

Answer (score 1):

you can try using the package 'plyr'

```
 install.packages('plyr');
 library('plyr');
 ddply(dt,.variables=c("y","x"),.fun=count)[,c(1:2,4)];
```

gives

```
   y x freq
 1 a a  2
 2 a b  1
 3 b a  1
 4 b b  2
```

Comment: But that's not what they asked for.